# Seleccionar determinadas filas de tabla MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Bueno pues tengo el siguiente código:

```
function dameTodosLosProyectos( $con, $cantidad = 0 )
{
    if( $cantidad > 0 )
    {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos LIMIT $cantidad";
    }else
        {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos";
        }
    return mysqli_query($con, $query);
 }
```

Con él puedo poner tanto:

```
   $result = dameTodosLosProyectos($link, 3); //Seleccionar primeras 3 filas
   $result = dameTodosLosProyectos($link); //Seleccionar todas las filas
```

Ahora, mi pregunta es:

- ¿Cómo selecciono tres filas pero no las tres primeras sino las tres últimas o empezando por la segunda (o sea la 2,3 y 4)?
- ¿Cómo selecciono por ejemplo la fila 2 y 3, para imprimirlas con cierto CSS, y luego coger la 4 y aplicarle otro código, etc.?

Comment: Creo que, dado que quieres hacer varios tipos de operaciones, es mejor pasar a la función toda la parte *especial* que quieres aplicar. Y dentro de la función, le agregas a la instrucción SQL el parámetro completo.

Answer (score 1):

En la definición de la función, añade un offset:

```
function dameTodosLosProyectos( $con, $cantidad = 0, $offset = 0 )
```

Despues adapta las SQL:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM proyectos LIMIT $cantidad OFFSET $offset";
```

Así cuando hagas:

```
$result = dameTodosLosProyectos($link, 3);
```

Puedes además decirle el offset:

```
$result = dameTodosLosProyectos($link, 3, 15);
```

Con lo que devolverá desde la 16, 3 registros.

También puedes definir la SQL así:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT $offset, $canitidad";
```

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que quería, y lo más importante... ¡funciona!